# Bind Textbox with textmode localdatetime to DateTime-Field in ObjectDataSource not evaluating

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm currently trying this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ReleasesDataSource"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" PageSize="35"
    ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Release timestamp">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="preTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("preTime") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="preTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("preTime"") %>' TextMode="DateTimeLocal"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
............
```

The timestamp is displayed correctly - but when i enter the Edit-Mode, I start with a textbox full of placeholders. So the present `DateTime`-Value in the `preTime` Field of the `ObjectDataSource` is not evaluated as I would expect with the `Bind() of the`preTime`-Field.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Your code snippet shows two consecutive double-quotes in Bind("preTime"") - is that a code typo or is that you're actual source?

Comment: Oops, sorry - that indeed is a code typo - not my actual source code.

Answer (score 1):

The correct formatting you need to resolve this issue is `Bind("preTime", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")`, or `Bind("preTime", "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}")` if you want to include the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<asp:TextBox ID="preTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Bind("preTime")).ToString("d") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Another solution is Implement the OnDataBinding event for the TextBox in the grid.

```
 protected void txtDate_OnDataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt = (TextBox)(sender);
txt.Text = (DateTime)(Bind("YourDateField")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue. Please add comment on how did you solve this issue?.  If the answer provided by stack overflow members is useful to you, please do not forget to up vote and accept the answer. You can also down vote if you think that answer is wrong or not useful.